# Symfony Security: Auth is not needed even if user doesn't match role

Tags: symfony, security, symfony-2.3

I encountered a strange issue. I have the following security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:
        ROLE_EDITOR:      [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDITOR]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: 123456, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
                    editor: { password: 123456, roles: [ 'ROLE_EDITOR' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        backend:
            pattern: ^/backend
            anonymous: ~
            provider: in_memory
            form_login:
                login_path: backend_login
                check_path: backend_login_check

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, host: example\.com$ }
        - { path: ^/backend_login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user/fetch, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/level, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/gallery, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I have an window development machine with XAMPP running and everything works out properly. I can log in to the backend and if I'm not logged in and try to open a backend route, I'm redirected to the login page.

This is my routing portion:

```
backend_login:
    pattern:    /backend_login
    defaults:   { _controller: FooBackendBundle:Security:login }

backend_login_check:
    pattern:   /backend/login_check
```

But when I'm uploading it to my integration linux server, I can open the backend without having to log in. It seems like Symfony does not care about the role the current user has.

The code and the symfony version are both the exact same (Symfony 2.3).

If I remove the `anonymous: ~` part from the backend firewall, it will redirect to the login page, but also creates an inifite redirection loop.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html):

> For each incoming request, Symfony checks each access_control entry to find one that matches the current request. As soon as it finds a matching access_control entry, it stops - only the first matching access_control is used to enforce access.

When you set `access_control` in your security config, you want to put your least-restrictive matches last.  In your case you will always match on the first pattern since all routes match on `^/` and therefore do not require any authentication.  Change your `access_control` to this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/backend_login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backend, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user/fetch, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/level, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/gallery, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I removed the `host` parameter as it didn't seem relevant.